# How to get json attribute value from geo json layer when mouse overring a subdivision?

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

I noticed that json has format like this:

```
{
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": 
    [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "310230",
        "properties": 
        {
            "name": "XXX District",
            "cp": [141.5637,61.5383 ],
            "childNum": 1
        },

        "geometry": 
        {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": 
            [.....]
        }
      }
    ]
 }
```

How to get the value of [features:properties:name](here is "XXX District") when mouse overring an point within corresponded admin subdivision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example http://openlayers.org/en/v3.14.2/examples/vector-layer.html, which demonstrates exactly what you're trying to do: load a GeoJSON and on mouse overring a feature display one of its properties.

The event you're looking for is the `ol.Map#pointermove` event.  To get the feature at a specific pixel, use the `ol.Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel` method

Here's a snippet:

```
map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
  if (evt.dragging) {
    return;
  }
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});
```

and inside the `displayFeatureInfo` method, to get the feature at pixel:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
  return feature;
});
```

and to get the property from a feature:

```
feature.get('name');
```